# dynamically change custom class in a nib (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nib

I have a nib in .xib format that defines a tableview cell.  It has a certain custom class assigned to it in the IB part of Xcode.  I use `table.register(StaffCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: StaffCell.reuseID)` where the nib and reuseID are static on the class.  We then use `table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StaffCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! StaffCell` to get a cell to use.  All is well.

We now have need for a subclass of the custom cell class to be able to be used (in a different view controller, which is a subclass of the main view controller where we are using this).  The subclass of the custom class doesn't change anything about the physical connections and the cell views and stuff don't change.  The subclass for the cell just changes some logic on the internal parameters.

I'd rather not have to copy and make a new nib (.xib) file just in order to be able to assign a new custom class (which is a subclass of the original).  Nothing but the custom class parameter is changing.

Is it possible to someway dynamically change the custom class of the nib before it instantiates the cell?

`table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StaffCellSubclass.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! StaffCellSubclass` crashes and burns at runtime with an error that it can't coerce the StaffCell into a StaffCellSubclass (I don't have the actual text of the error as it was a co-worker with whom I was team coding that had the actual error on screen).  (The reuseID points to the same nib)

Thanks

Comment: When designing a "cell.xib" in IB, the Class is assigned to the cell object. UIKit does a lot "behind the scenes" which is why you can use that directly with`table.register(StaffCell.nib ...)`  -- no additional "extract objects from nib" code necessary. So, you won't be able to subclass it the way you're asking. You do say: *"The subclass for the cell just changes some logic on the internal parameters."* Is there some reason you can't code that into the existing class? it's very difficult to answer questions in the abstract... try to provide details so it makes sense.

Comment: The existing class is unrelated in terms of the "use".  Mixing in the new logic makes the separations messy.   It would be nice if you could do something like nib = myNib.setCustomClass(class.self) or something like that before you try and use the dequeue and it creates an in-memory copy of the nib using the new custom class.  Obviously the new copied and updated nib would be the one registered.

Comment: Well, unless you feel you are getting some big benefit from using a XIB for your cell... you could write a "base" cell class with all of the UI setup, and then subclass that for your different logic/use cases.

Comment: It's existing code that is being updated with some new functionality. No time or support for a rewrite of the cell. Thanks though!  For now we'll just copy the xib file.

Comment: Duplicating the xib is certainly an option... but unless it's an incredibly complex xib, it couldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to write it in code -- giving you much more flexibility down the line. Worth considering anyway.

Comment: We could also load the nib by hand inside the class.  Based on our tie and resources and the priority of this the copy is the easiest.  We're under staffed at the moment...  I appreciate your comments on this! @DonMag